# Last letter vertical cut by IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

I'm using the Google font Oswald in the top nav of [this website](http://www.mitomanias.com.ar/) and it  works great in all browsers. But, in two different IE11, installed in two different computers, half of times the page is loaded the last letters of some strings are cut:

[image: last letter cut]

These are captures of the IE working OK (green dots) and the IE showing the issue (red dots):

[image]

As you can see, it looks like the text itself is rendering with the same width in both browsers but, in the browser with the issue the containers wrapping the text are not expanding enough.

The worst part is that it is happening only in my client's computers, and I can't reproduce the issue.

I've made an extended research and I tried many things:

1. Changing font-weight
2. Checking that no local Oswald font is installed in the machine
3. Using Oswald font downloaded from Font Squierrel, instead of the Google Font
4. Changing font-size, word-spacing, letter-spacing, deactivating text-transform and text-shadow
5. Activating/deactivating Windows ClearType

If my client press refresh in the IE with the issue, half of the times the page loads OK. Also, if he inspects the code and activates and reactivates one of the styles, for example font-size, the problem fixes.

The issue doesn't happen with normal fonts or with

UPDATE:

I made a [jsfiddle minimum model](http://jsfiddle.net/ac8dn5cu/3/) that reproduces the issue. I added two other text blocks using different Google fonts and the issue only affects the Oswald font.
My client says that the issue appears very frequently when he uses CTRL-F5 instead of F5.

[image]

In the case you can't access jsfiddle, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type='text/css'>
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300);
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bowlby+One&v2);
            body {
                background: #ccc;
            }
            .container {
                width: 158px;
            }
            .container h2 a {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                line-height: 1.5em;
            }
            .container h2 a:hover {
                color: #ecd6bc;
            }
            .container.one h2 a {
                font-family: 'Oswald';
            }
            .container.two h2 a {
                font-family: 'Droid Sans';
            }
            .container.three h2 a {
                font-family: 'Bowlby One';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container one">
            <h2><a href="http://www.example.com">Suspendisse nec metus quis nunc cursus fringilla.</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container two">
            <h2><a href="http://www.example.com">Suspendisse nec metus quis nunc cursus fringilla.</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container three">
            <h2><a href="http://www.example.com">Suspendisse nec metus quis nunc cursus fringilla.</a></h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see this issue when you're using standard fonts as well? I am testing on IE11 with both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 and am not able to repro the issue. Could you build a reduced example that contains no more code than is necessary to illustrate the issue?

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I edited the whole post in order to answer your question. I made a jsfiddle example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;
```

Refere this source for more details [source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).